# Calculate path from node X to other nodes using a given javascript object with parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, dijkstra

Consider there is a graph with 7 nodes T,U,V,X,W,Y,Z.

I have a Javascript object which contains the parent of each node after calculating the shortest path from node X.

```
parents {"T":"V","U":"V","V":"X","W":"X","X":"X","Y":"X","Z":"X"}
```

ex:

```
parent of T is V
parent of U is V
```

Using the above object I need to calculate the path for each node from X.

ex:

```
X->X :  X
X->Y :  XY
X->Z :  XZ
X->T :  XVT
X->U :  XVU
```

So I need a simple program in **JAVASCRIPT** which will output the path to an object name **path**.

```
ex:
path {"X":"X", "Y":"XY", "Z":"XZ", "T":"XVT", "U":"XVU", "W":"XW"}
```

Any  help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Help with what? You haven't shown the code you have that attempts to solve this yourself. Stackoverflow isn't  a free code writing service. The idea here is to help you with **your code** not do all the work for you. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

general idea is to use [dfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm. This is very basic, the only thing is to find nodes to which you should navigate on each recursive call, here is some code with explanation:

```
let func = (parents) => {
   let ans = {}; // ans will contain all of our paths 
   let dfs = (X, path) => { // dfs function to run over tree
     ans[X] = path; // putting current path to current vertex
     let neighbours = [];
     Object.keys(parents).forEach(key => {
       if (parents[key] == X) { // looking for vertices where X is parent 
          neighbours.push(key);
       }
     });
     if (parents[X] != null) { // looking for parent of X
        neighbours.push(X);
     }
     neighbours.forEach(neighbour => { // iterating over all of the neighbour vetrices
       if (!ans[neighbour]) { // if it is not visited 
        dfs(neighbour, path + neighbour); // go into it with updated path
       }
     })
   };
   dfs("X", "X"); // run on initial node
   return ans; // don't forget to return calculated answer
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @sreja Nagin. This worked like a charm.